# Show/Append div if jQuery datepicker selected date is less than 5 years old

Tags: jquery, if-statement, datepicker

Im using the jQuery Datepicker for date of birth input.

I want to show or append some text above the input field if the age of the person is less than 5 years old.

So im guessing i would get todays date as a variable and also todays date minus 5 years and then say: If their selected date is between today and  (todays date minus 5 years) then show this message. But im struggling how to do so!

Answer (score 0):

On your DateField add OnChange event called dateChange()

```
function dateChange() {
var d = new Date();
var currYear = d.getFullYear();  -- Returns the year
var dateSelected = document.getElementfromId("<your Date Element ID>")
-- you can use parsing based on the date format you use in datePicker. 

-- find the difference between currYear  and year user choose
if (diffrence < 5){
-- write your code
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Iv got the below now which im hoping works, but as the datepicker is added by a plugin, im not able to add the OnChange event. Do you know what i can do?

`function dateChange() {
    var d = new Date();
      alert(d);
    var currYear = d.getFullYear(); // -- Returns the year
    var dateSelected = document.getElementfromId("eo-booking-field-26");

    var selectedYear = dateSelected.substr(dateSelected.length - 4);
    var currYear5Years = currYear - 5;
    
    if ((selectedYear < currYear) && (selectedYear > currYear5Years)){
       alert(selectedYear);
    }
}`

Comment: Iv also just realised this doesn't work as its only focussing on the year and not the other parts which are necessary.

For example, if they were born March 5 2012, (and today is March 5 2017), they would still be under 5 years old, but because my code is only comparing the year, it thinks otherwise

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datepicker's onSelect event. Unfortunately, onSelect fires whenever a date is selected, even if it hasn't changed. This is a design flaw in the datepicker: It always fires onSelect (even if nothing changed), and doesn't fire any event on the underlying input on change. (If you look in the code of that example, we're listening for changes, but they aren't being raised.) It should probably fire an event on the input when things change (possibly the usual change event, or possibly a datepicker-specific one).       If you like, of course, you can make the change event on the input fire:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
  onSelect: function() {
    $(this).change();
  }
});
```

That will fire change on the underlying input for any handler hooked up via jQuery. But again, it always fires it. If you want to only fire on a real change, you'll have to save the previous value (possibly via data) and compare.

Use the below function to find difference between two dates.

```
 // datepart: 'y', 'm', 'w', 'd', 'h', 'n', 's'
Date.dateDiff = function(datepart, fromdate, todate) {  
  datepart = datepart.toLowerCase();    
  var diff = todate - fromdate; 
  var divideBy = { w:604800000, 
                   d:86400000, 
                   h:3600000, 
                   n:60000, 
                   s:1000 };    

  return Math.floor( diff/divideBy[datepart]);
}
```